Cannot flag or edit broken link in historically locked question
I recently took a look at Why is cleverness considered harmful in programming by some people? and noticed that the WordPress article it linked to does not exist anymore. I wanted to edit it or flag it to get the link replaced with a copy from the Wayback Machine but both the edit and flag actions are missing.
Is there a way to bring attention to this (aside from asking on Meta)?

According to the Help Center, this is indeed intended behavior, but I do find it strange that flagging is also disabled for the historical significance lock. I would use Meta for this purpose, since there's no better option.
I updated this question with a Wayback Machine link, so this is all set.

comments in h/l questions are flaggable. If memory serves I used this trick a while ago - can't remember though if it was here or at SO
